Doubt from EGMO book.(Theorem about radical axis and concyclic points)
The photo of the EGMO page I am talking aboutIn Theorem 2.9 of EGMO book,we are using the fact that AB,CD intersect at radical axis to prove that A,B,C,D are concyclic.But to prove that AB,CD intersect at radical axis we need to prove that A,B,C,D are concyclic(Theorem 2.7).So we are assuming the statements to prove the facts.Can anyone help clear my doubt?(I am a beginner to EGMO book)

Err, it’s pretty common to show facts A and B are equivalent by showing that A implies B and B implies A.
